# Indices of true values

Tags: rust

My task is to find the indices of a vector of booleans that are `true`. I'm coming from a JavaScript background and would like to learn how to write this in idiomatic Rust.

```
fn main() {
    let fold_func = |acc: Vec<usize>, p: (usize, &bool)| -> Vec<usize> {
        if *p.1 {
            let mut clone = acc.clone();
            clone.push(p.0);
            clone
        } else {
            acc
        }
    };
    let v = vec![true,false,true];
    let result = v.iter().enumerate().fold(vec![], fold_func);
    print!("{:?}", result) //[0, 2]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Spaces come after commas

   ```
   -    let v = vec![true,false,true];
   +    let v = vec![true, false, true];
   ```
2. Define the closure inline in the `fold` call. This allows removing the explicit types
3. Cloning the accumulator is more expensive than it needs to be. You have been given ownership of the vector, just declare it mutable and push to it.

The code now looks like:

```
let result = v.iter().enumerate().fold(vec![], |mut acc, p| {
    if *p.1 {
        acc.push(p.0);
        acc
    } else {
        acc
    }
});
```

4. Extract out the common part of the closure that returns the `acc`
5. Destructure `p` to give the components names.

The code now looks like:

```
let result = v.iter().enumerate().fold(vec![], |mut acc, (index, value)| {
    if *value {
        acc.push(index);
    }
    acc
});
```

6. I advocate to basically memorize all the methods on `Iterator`. In this case, `filter`, `map`, and `collect` allow writing the entire thing more succinctly, equally efficiently, as well as more flexibly.
7. There's no need to allocate the `Vec`, an array / slice works the same.

The code now looks like:

```
fn main() {
    let v = [true, false, true];

    let result: Vec<_> = v.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter(|&(_, &value)| value)
        .map(|(index, _)| index)
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

---

> I would expect that `filter()` filters out non true values, so indices would shift, but it seems like it's not happening

Yes, `filter` does remove the non-true values. The important thing to recognize is where the indices are added.

With `iter().enumerate().filter()`, enumeration happens *before* the filtering. Each index is added based on an unfiltered iterator.

If the code had instead been `iter().filter().enumerate()`, the enumeration happening *after* the filtering, then the index would have been added based on the filtered iterator. This would result in the indices `0, 1, 2, ...`, which isn't very useful, as you point out.

Comment: Huge thanks for that!, ca n you explain why `N.7` is working - I would expect that `filter()` filters out non true values, so indices would shift, but it seems like it's not happening

Comment: @dark_ruby updated